# How to recover MongoDB prompt from '>' to secondary node prompt?

Tags: mongodb, linux

I got three test servers using MongoDB 4 with cluster resultset. I stopped the primary node and MongoDB prompt on secondary node changed from 'rsExample:SECONDARY>' to '>'. Then, I started the primary node but MongoDB prompt on secondary node didn't change.

Is there any MongoDB command to restore the prompt from '>' to 'rsExample:SECONDARY>'?

Comment: How did you connect? If you connect properly to a Replica set (see [Replica Set with Members on Different Machines](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#replica-set-with-members-on-different-machines)) then a simple "ENTER" should restore your prompt.

Comment: I connect by mongo -u "admin" -p --authenticationDatabase "admin"

Comment: That's wrong, see linked documentation

Comment: I don't think it's wrong to connect to mongoDB node. I think it's considered like other way. On the other side, I made testing according to your advice, but when I start the primary node again the prompt changes to '>' on secondary node. Therefore, it happens the same. The easy way is exiting the shell and logging again on secondary node. I don't see in MongoDB shell a command where the prompt '>' was refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You need to "tell" the replica set that, that you want that first node to be primary whenever it's possible.

That is done by defining the 'priority' of the first node higher than other nodes. [Here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/adjust-replica-set-member-priority/#:%7E:text=The%20value%20of%20priority%20can,have%20priority%20set%20to%200%20.) you can find how!

Comment: The priority nodes were established. Primary (node 1) Priority: 15, Secondary (node 2) Priority: 8 Secondary (Node 3) Priority: 1. Do you mean I have to change the priority on one of these nodes once Primary was stopped? If so, in which node?

Comment: No need to change a priority. That node that has the highest priority AND has up-to-date content will be selected as PRIMARY. So, when node 1 "comes back", it will start at first as secondary, then update its content and when it has all changes replicated, it will come as PRIMARY again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be difficult. When you connect to a single node with `mongo -u "admin" -p --authenticationDatabase "admin"` and the `mongod` service on this node stops, then the connection is lost, i.e. the default prompt changes to `>`. This state remains even if you restart the `mongod` process.

You have to exit the shell and reconnect or use the [Mongo()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Mongo/) command.

Even a redefinition of `prompt` variable does not work.

However, the new mongo shell `mongosh` performs a reconnect automatically and restores the prompt.

Anyway, the best way would be to connect to the replica set, rather than to a single node, e.g.

```
mongo "mongodb://admin:password@host_1:27017,host_2:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=repSet"
```

then the connection remains active or reconnect automatically even is you stop the PRIMARY. If you want to read data from SECONDARY for whatever reason then better use the [Read Preference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference/#std-label-read-preference)